# Is there a way to keep a creature fascinated even if its opponent approaches?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, saving-throw

A cursed weapon I'm considering introducing to the campaign causes the wielder, after the wielder slays a foe with the weapon, to make a Willpower saving throw (DC 16). Failure means for 1d6 days the wielder suffers from the affliction [mania/phobia](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/afflictions/madness/mania-phobia)—specifically, a mania triggered by creatures of the same kind that were most recently killed.

The PCs will likely employ the weapon against [trolls](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/humanoids/giants/troll) occupying a large underground cave system that have kidnapped some villagers. The weapon'll give the PCs a serious advantage over the trolls, but one or more PCs might also become [fascinated](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Fascinated) repeatedly by the trolls. What I want to avoid is having the condition fascinated ending whenever a troll moves closer, therefore rendering the curse largely moot. The condition [fascinated](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Fascinated) reads:

> Any potential threat, such as a hostile creature approaching, allows the fascinated creature a new saving throw against the fascinating effect. Any obvious threat, such as someone drawing a weapon, casting a spell, or aiming a ranged weapon at the fascinated creature, automatically breaks the effect.

The best idea I've come up with is to have the [mania](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/afflictions/madness/mania-phobia) work like the [scarecrow](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/constructs/scarecrow) supernatural ability fascinating gaze, which reads:

> The approach or animation of the scarecrow does not count as an obvious threat to the victim of this particular fascination effect (although the scarecrow's attack does count as an obvious threat and ends the fascination immediately).

Is there a better way to keep the weapon's curse relevant or a different way to cause the wielder momentary inconvenience that probably needs friendly intervention? I don't want to use a deadlier condition like [dazed](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Dazed), [staggered](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Staggered), or [stunned](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Stunned).

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve here? Why do you not want the fascination to break?

Comment: I did some editing on this. I had to do some research to determine what you meant by *mania*, so I thought others might benefit from the links. Feel free to change whatever to put this more in line with what you're looking for as I did some reading between the lines.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's pretty much what I'm looking for and still learning how to link and such.

Comment: It sounds like you want published material as a precedent for this effect; if so, you should edit the question to say so. Also, it might be good if you indicated why *specifically* this effect (an affliction) is the one you want to use; I took a guess, but I don't know if it's accurate. That is, if this is only *pretty much* what you're looking for and not *actually* what you're looking for, *my* feelings are unhurt by you editing your own question. `:-)`

Comment: Basically what I'm looking for is for the weapon to make the PC obsessed/crazy.  Storywise the weapon is called Trollslaughter, the group is given a clue that this spaces to Troll Slaughter instead of Troll's Laughter. After the user kills a troll with it, it drives him a little insane.  Auditory hallucinations (ie. Laughter) are generally symptoms of Mania or Schizophrenia.  Both of which have rules in the Gamemastery Guide. I wanted to go with Mania so it wouldn't be as severe of a detriment to the PC

Answer (score 2):

You could base it on the Red Mantis Assassin (Crimson Assassin Prestige class) ability Prayer Attack, but with a limited duration - fascinated by the red mantis assassin on a failed save, only getting saving throws if additional threats appear.

Thematically you could skin this as mania relating to each individual troll/monster - the PC effectively gets a saving throw per troll.

This would allow you to control any second chance to save against it by controlling when and how monsters or new sources of threat appear or don't appear.